# OpenCV SURF class Error

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, surf

I find that OpenCV's new class [SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=surf#surf) does not act the same as `SurfFeatureDetector`. What's wrong with it?

Some example with two pictures:

..................................`img_1`..................................................................... `img_2`...................................

[image: img_1] [image: img_2]

use it like `./a.out ./img_1.png ./img_2.png`

```
// STL
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
// C-Standard
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
// OpenCV
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>

void print(const std::string & filename, const std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>> & vec) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "w");
    fprintf(file, "{\n");
    for(auto & i : vec)
        fprintf(file, "    { {%d,%d,%f}, {,%d,%d,%f} },\n",
                i[0].queryIdx, i[0].trainIdx, i[0].distance,
                i[1].queryIdx, i[1].trainIdx, i[1].distance);
    fprintf(file, "}\n");
    fclose(file);
}

void test1(const std::string & imgf_1, const std::string & imgf_2) {
    cv::Mat img_1;
    cv::Mat img_2;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;
    cv::Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>> matches;

    img_1 = cv::imread(imgf_1);
    img_2 = cv::imread(imgf_2);
    int minhessin = 400;
    cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector(minhessin);
    cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    cv::BFMatcher bfMatcher(cv::NORM_L2);

    keypoints_1.clear(); keypoints_2.clear();
    detector.detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
    extractor.compute(img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
    detector.detect(img_2, keypoints_2);
    extractor.compute(img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);
    matches.clear();
    bfMatcher.knnMatch(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches, 2);

    print("main_bak.log", matches);
}

void test2(const std::string & imgf_1, const std::string & imgf_2) {
    cv::Mat img_1;
    cv::Mat img_2;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;
    cv::Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>> matches;

    img_1 = cv::imread(imgf_1);
    img_2 = cv::imread(imgf_2);
    const double hessianThreshold = 400;
    cv::SURF detector2(hessianThreshold);
    cv::BFMatcher bfMatcher(cv::NORM_L2);

    keypoints_1.clear(); keypoints_2.clear();
    detector2(img_1, cv::Mat(), keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
    detector2(img_2, cv::Mat(), keypoints_2, descriptors_2);
    matches.clear();
    bfMatcher.knnMatch(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches, 2);

    print("main.log", matches);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(argc < 3) {
        std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " img_1 img_2" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    test1(argv[1], argv[2]);
    test2(argv[1], argv[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

The log's heading 5 lines are shown here:

*main_bak.log*:

```
{
    { {0,0,0.000787}, {,0,2,0.126846} },
    { {1,1,0.001695}, {,1,167,0.353709} },
    { {2,2,0.000860}, {,2,0,0.127105} },
    { {3,3,0.002939}, {,3,5,0.333215} },
    { {4,4,0.001360}, {,4,115,0.294008} },
```

*main.log*:

```
{
    { {0,0,0.000900}, {,0,2,0.143810} },
    { {1,1,0.024048}, {,1,107,0.621702} },
    { {2,2,0.003646}, {,2,0,0.144049} },
    { {3,3,0.032238}, {,3,5,0.604136} },
    { {4,4,0.001449}, {,4,87,0.591502} },
```

Comment: Not really a programming question... Maybe the way the algorithms parameter are handled ?

Comment: I know it's not a programming question. However, the distance changing from '0.001695' to '0.024048' might due to some problems.

Comment: In the function `test1`, declare extractor as `cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor(minHessian);`

Comment: @sgarizvi Yeah, you got it right. Thx. Please answer it, so that I can mark you as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes `cv::SurfFeatureDetector` and `cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor` are aliases of the class `cv::SURF`. The difference in results is due to the following reason:

In the function `test1`, `detector` and `extractor` objects are being initialized with different parameters. `detector` is using `minHessian` value of **400** while extractor is using the opencv implementation defined default value.

In function `test2`, keypoint detection and descriptor computation are done using a single `cv::SURF` object with `hessianThreshold` value of **400**.

To reproduce the results of `test2` in `test1`, initialize both objects with same parameters like this:

```
int minhessin = 400;
cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector(minhessin);
cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor(minHessian);
```